# After assigning DIM values & range NEED to include highlighted color of cell too

Tags: excel, vba

I have code (see below) which assigns dims, sets the range for each, then opens new workbook, finds first empty row and inserts the values into each offset column appropriately.  What I now need to do, somehow! is also copy the cell color and place it in the new workbook too for each DIM.  Anyone have any ideas based on this working script?  (There are actually 29 DIM's set but only included one for ease of use.)

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim itemLast As String
Dim myAuthorization As Workbook

Worksheets("Sheet2").Select

itemLast = Range("C10")    
Set myAuthorization = Workbooks.Open("M:\authorizations.xlsm")

Worksheets("Sheet1").Select    
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Select

RowCount = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count    
With Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")    
    .Offset(RowCount, 0) = itemLast    
End With

myAuthorization.Save    
myAuthorization.Close

End Sub
```

Comment: Try getting the `cells.interior.color` property and use it to set your target cell's interior.color property.

Comment: Just copy and `PasteSpecial` the value and color at once.

Comment: Brian, I did look at this "function" but absolutely could not figure out how to apply it to my current macro.  Can it be a single line before assigning the dimensions to the new cells or does it need to be for each?  For example, could I do the ".Offset(rowcount, 0)=itemLast.pastespecial..."  and if so, how do I ensure that it was actually copied at the top when I set the itemLast=Range(C"10").  This is what I would prefer to do, but just do not have the knowledge.  Thanks if you have any ideas!

Answer (score 1):

Untested:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim rngFrom As Range, rngTo As Range
    Dim myAuth As Workbook

    Set myAuth = Workbooks.Open("M:\authorizations.xlsm")

    Set rngFrom = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("C10")
    Set rngTo = myAuth.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)

    rngTo.Value = rngFrom.Value
    rngTo.Interior.Color = rngFrom.Interior.Color

    myAuth.Close SaveChanges:=True

End Sub
```

To explain:

```
Set rngTo = myAuth.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
```

We want to find the first empty row on that sheet, looking in Col A (and working from the bottom of the sheet upwards)

```
Cells(Rows.Count, 1)
```

is starting on the last row of the sheet in Col A (Col 1).  From there

```
End(xlUp)
```

is the same as pressing Ctrl+Up - it will take you *up* to the first occupied cell in that column.  From there

```
Offset(1, 0)
```

moves that position by 1 row down (and zero columns across)

Comment: Tim, I REALLY appreciate the feedback!  Could I impose on you to help me out a touch more and utilize my DIM variable as an example.  I'm REALLY new to this and was fortunate enough to find a video that properly explained my current script to me.  So, I'm not sure how to apply the rngTo/rngFrom to my current dimensions.  Thanks!

Comment: The way you had it set up in your question would have meant even more code was required to extend the copy to include the fill color.  `rngFrom` and `rngTo` are just pointers to specific cells which allow you to access the properties of those cells (.Value, .Interior.Color, etc)

Comment: Ok, then I will take the next step to add these new variables to my existing code.  Thanks again for the assist.  I'll let you know how it works out.

Comment: Tim!  You are the bomb!  I don't know how I can ever thank you for this!  It works!  Yay!  I only had to make one small modification that took a little bit to figure out.  I don't understand the code 100% but I am glad that this worked.  I'll put the line that needed to change in the next comment block.

Comment: (I should say I don't understand this particular line of code 100%)       Set rngColorTo = myAuthorization.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(RowCount, 1).Offset(1, 0)

Comment: Cool!  I appreciate the explanation.  I guess I was thrown off a bit because I defined the row.count with RowCount = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count  and therefore just replaced your Row.Count with my RowCount variable and this worked.  Again, you're the best!  Wish I could reciprocate but alas, you're the man!